# Can't click button more than one time when append html data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I've a problem with jquery. I use ajax to send id to delete from DB and then return html file to update content without reload page (I use struts 2) , first time run or reload page my button work fine ( row was deleted and my content was updated) but when I try to click button again , it doesn't respond.

[image]

My script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $(".btnEdit").click(function() {
                alert("Edit");
            });
            $(".btnDelete").click(function() {
                id = $(this).attr('id');
                alert("Delete ID : " + id);
                $.ajax({
                    url: "delete",
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {'id': id},
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                        $('.catagoryContent').remove();
                        $('.container').append(data);
                    },
                    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert("error");
                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

Sorry, I forgot return data code.

```
<div class="catagoryContent">
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Edit / Delete</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <s:iterator value="catagoryList" var="catagory">
            <tr>
                <td>${catagory.id}</td>
                <td>${catagory.name}</td>
                <td>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary btnEdit" id="${catagory.id}">Edit</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-warning btnDelete" id="${catagory.id}">Delete</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </s:iterator>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: is your `btnDelete` button nested in `.catagoryContent` block?

Comment: Try `$(document).delegate('.btnDelete', 'click', function(){...})` instead of `$(".btnDelete").click(function(){...})`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At document ready you initialize all tags with class "btnDelete" to the click function.
When you do a successfully ajax call, you replace all your content with response from the server.
At that point you remove all your buttons and add new data with new buttons.

jQuery is not listening to these buttons because the $(".btnDelete").click(... was only set at page load.

if you change

```
$(".btnDelete").click(function() {
```

to

```
$(document).on("click", ".btnDelete", function() {
```

it will still work after you add new data to .container
The "on" function also triggers when you dynamically add new tags with class ".btnDelete" (See [here](http://api.jquery.com/on/))

Comment: I would not use document as a context, but the nearest parent.

Answer (score 1):

This is because `click` event handler is attached at the page startup.
But when you reload the part of your page, old button with onclick handler is being removed.

The decision is to use

```
$(document.body).delegate('.btnDelete', 'click', function(){...})
```

instead of

```
$(".btnDelete").click(function(){...})
```

This way you will attach event handler to body element (which will fire always), and jQuery will check whether the clicked element has class `.btnDelete`, or not.
So it will work even if you delete these buttons and then insert new ones.

Another approach is to attach onclick handlers to the buttons every time they created, but I think the first approach is easier

Answer (score 0):

You aren't listening to the `click` event on your updated html.

You should use

```
$list.on('click', '.btnEdit', function() { ... })
```

where `$list` is the element containing the items (probably a `<ul>`)