# Reload content function is breaking the codes

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am making a comment and replies form, for each comment the replies will show under if there is any as shown by [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYhK4.jpg)  sorry for the none sense comments but i ran out of ideas ^D^. So I managed to make things work to a certain point which is: I can post replies normally but when i want to delete a reply, i must refresh the page, and when i refresh i can delete 1 reply per comment and no more than 1 because other buttons doesn't click anymore only the first that i click on works. I debugged the codes by pasting line by line to see when the problem happens and i found out that it happens when i call this function to the codes : `loadBoardReplies(boardCommentId);`
when i remove this function, all the buttons clicks normally and return the value to the console, i tried to take this function outside of the click function but i found out that i can not because i need to refer to which button was clicked by using " this "

here are the full jquery and ajax codes :

```
        // Delete a reply
$(".delete_board_reply_button").one("click", function(){ 

    var deleteReplyButtonParent = $(this).attr("id");
    var boardReplyIdArray = deleteReplyButtonParent.split("-");
    var boardReplyId = boardReplyIdArray[0];

    //console.log(boardReplyId);

    var parent_div = $(this).parent().parent().prev().prev().attr("id");
    //var numRepliesLink = parent_div.children("#board_num_replies");
    //console.log(parent_div);
    var url = "widgets/delete_board_reply.php";

    $.ajax({
        url: url, 
        method: "POST",
        data: {
            reply_id: boardReplyId,
            comment_id: parent_div
        },
        success: function(data){
            // here i make a custom pop up alert
            var repliesWord = "";
            if (data == 0) {
                repliesWord = "("+data+") replies";
            } else if (data == 1) {
                repliesWord = "("+data+") reply";
            } else if (data > 1) {
                repliesWord = "("+data+") replies";
            }
            $("#"+parent_div+"-board_num_replies").html(repliesWord);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            console.log(jqXHR);
        }
    });
    var commentIdAttr = $(this).parent().parent().attr("id");
    var commentArray = commentIdAttr.split("-");
    var boardCommentId = commentArray[0];
    console.log(boardCommentId);
    loadBoardReplies(boardCommentId);
// if i remove the line above this, if i comment it every button works fine and print the boardCommentId to the console
});

function loadBoardReplies (value) {
    var url = "widgets/board_reply_fetch.php";

    $.ajax({
        url: url, 
        method: "POST",
        data: {
            comment_id: value
        },
        success: function(data){
            $("#"+value+"-showBoardReplies").html(data);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            console.log(jqXHR);
        }
    });
}
```

and here are the html codes :

```
                    <div id="<?php echo $board_comment_id_number;?>-showBoardReplies" class="reply_comment_div_big">
                <?php 
                        $reply_data = find_board_replies_by_comment_id($comment_id);

                        while ($reply_assoc = mysqli_fetch_assoc($reply_data)) {
                            $reply_id = $reply_assoc['reply_id'];
                            $reply_comment_id = $reply_assoc['comment_id'];
                            $reply_board_id = $reply_assoc['board_id'];
                            $reply_user_id = $reply_assoc['user_id'];
                            $reply_text = $reply_assoc['reply'];
                            $reply_timestamp = $reply_assoc['reply_timestamp'];

                            $reply_user_data = find_user_data_by_id($reply_user_id);

                            if ($reply_count !== 0) {       
                    ?> 

                    <div class="reply_comment_div" id="<?php echo $reply_id;?>-boardReplyDelete">
                        <a href="profile.php?user_id=<?php echo (int)$reply_user_id;?>" class="board_comments_div_picture">
                            <img src="
                            <?php 
                                $profile_image = $reply_user_data['profile_picture']; 
                                $profile_image_thumb = "uploaded_pictures/profile/$reply_user_id/" . $reply_user_id . "small.png";

                                if ($profile_image == "") {
                                    if ($comment_user_data['gender'] == "Male"){
                                        echo "images/ProfilePicMale.png";
                                    } else {
                                        echo "images/ProfilePicFemale.png";
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    echo $profile_image_thumb;
                                }


                          ?>" width="50px" height="50px" alt="" title=""/>
                        </a>

                        <a href="profile.php?user_id=<?php echo (int)$reply_user_id;?>" class="board_comments_reply_link"><?php echo ucfirst(htmlentities($reply_user_data['first_name'])) . " " . ucfirst(htmlentities($reply_user_data['last_name']));?></a>
                    <?php 
                        if ($reply_user_id == $_SESSION['user_id']){ 
                    ?>
                        <a href="edit_reply_board.php?reply_id=<?php echo $reply_id;?>" class="edit_comment_button_board">Edit</a>
                        <input type="button" class="delete_board_reply_button" id="<?php echo $reply_id;?>-replyId" value="Delete"/>
                    <?php 
                        }
                    ?>
                        <div class="board_comment_submited_on">
                            submitted <?php echo time_of_post($reply_timestamp);?>
                        </div>
                        <span class="comment_content_span"><?php echo nl2br($reply_text);?></span>
                    </div>

                    <?php 
                            }
                        }
                    ?>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1) It seems you are dynamically-creating elements, therefore you should be using [delegated event handlers](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/#event-propagation).

Instead of

```
$(".delete_board_reply_button").one("click", function(){
```

do

```
$(document).on("click", ".delete_board_reply_button", function(){
```

2) I would also suggest you to not use chained `.parent()` to find elements, but use [.closest(selector)](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) instead.

For example, instead of

```
$(this).parent().parent().attr("id")
```

do

```
$(this).closest('.reply_comment_div_big').attr("id")
```

Likewise, instead of chained `.prev()` use [.sibling(selector)](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/).

3) Utilize [HTML5 data-attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) for storing IDs instead of using weird named `id` attribute.

You can use [.data()](https://api.jquery.com/data/#data2) to get the value.

Comment: thank you Mikey for your solution, i will look into it tomorrow when i get back from work, because i just got home and it is late now

Comment: hello Mikey i changed to this function and still it worked one time only for one reply i managed to delete 1 reply and can't click anymore delete buttons :
`$('.reply_comment_div').on("click", "input", function(){ `

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION FOUND**
I kept searching and searching until i found similar question, well as Mikey gave the solution but i made a mistake using the delegate() function
[Can't click button more than one time when append html data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20968042/cant-click-button-more-than-one-time-when-append-html-data)